# Enjoying the memory footprint of struct-like in ruby

Tags: ruby, memory, struct, hash

I have a case where I am having a lot of small records. I.e., many of them, but each record usually has less than 10 fields.
I want to use named placeholders, just like C-strcut. As there will be a LOT of them (tens of millions, maybe more), hence, I will require a memory efficient implementation.
Ruby has Struct and Hash. I know that Hash may allocate more memory than is needed. Is Strcut, by design, more memory efficient? I.e., I could run some empirical tests, but I want to know that this is the intent, and that it is probably checked, for future versions.
These building blocks exist in Perl and Python, and that would influence my decision.

Comment: There are some benchmarks that compare the two: https://gist.github.com/tristang/a961fdc327e7d79439729a6c381227dc

Comment: Memory efficiency is an implementation detail. Ruby (at the language level) doesn't specify it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a speed benchmark, not footprint. If one needs to swap, the slow can become different.

Comment: You might also want to check JRuby versus CRuby.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmarks here:

https://gist.github.com/rmosolgo/3a2876dbbb721749176644da7325827e.

For Ruby 2.4,

```
Comparison:
               Class:  9394405.5 i/s
             Hash#[]:  8318559.1 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
              Struct:  8074174.5 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
          Hash#fetch:  6148417.9 i/s - 1.53x  slower
          OpenStruct:  3918462.1 i/s - 2.40x  slower
```

Looks like Structs (and actual hashes, accessed by the `[]` method, are almost as performant as actual (small) classes. I think what you're looking for here are benchmarking tools, just in case you need to really figure out things (not just for this example). I suggest checking out [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) for speed, [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) for profiling, [memory_profiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/memory_profiler) for memory (I have only used benchmark-ips and ruby-prof).

Alternatives to classes/hashes/etc.. include these gems: [values](https://github.com/tcrayford/Values) and [dry-struct](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-struct). I've only used dry-struct, it provide a small typing system that makes me honest re: passing in values.

Good luck.